# Origin of "in the drink"

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

I know what this means, but can't figure out why ponds, lakes, or oceans might be referred to as "the drink."

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drink#Noun):

> (colloquial, with the) Any body of water.
>
> If he doesn't pay off the mafia, he’ll wear cement shoes to the bottom of the drink!

Comment: I don't know where or when this metaphoric extension became popular, but here are a couple of instances from the early 1870s of [fell in the drink](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fell+in+the+drink%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22fell+in+the+drink%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&sa=X&ei=tWTnUdjpC9Ka0AWN8YGoAQ&ved=0CCUQpwUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099%2Cd.d2k%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=e8bc257db55b4054&biw=1288&bih=838). It may have been early sailor's "ironic" slang (because they *couldn't* drink  seawater if the fresh water ran out! !)

Comment: He'd be swimmin wit da fishes

Comment: Because it's wet? Or liquid? Same reason a golfer might call a sand trap a [beach](http://www.thegolfexpert.com/lingo-b.php).

Answer (score 2):

OED1 (1897) has the following in its entry for the noun *drink*:

1. U.S. humorous. A river or body of water.
   Big drink : the Mississippi ; also, the Atlantic.
   1857 Holland *Bay Path* xii. 137 So you'd better scull
   your dug-out over the drink again, a i860 N. Y. *Spirit of
   Times* (Bartlett *Dict. Amer*, s.v. *Big*), Off I sot, went
   through Mississippi, crossed the big drink. 1873 Roots
   (1888) 47 If you don't sit steady, we shall be spilt into the drink.

Thus, reference to a large body of water as a *drink* was established by the 1850's.  But such usage as *in the drink* may be somewhat older than that. OED1's second main entry for the verb  *drink* is like

> Drink,  Obs. Aphetic f. ADRINK, to drown.
>   c 1425 Seven Sag. ...
>   Hadde I than be dronken,
>   And in the salt flod sonkyn.

Cites for *adrink* are dated from 880 AD to 1300 AD.  *[Aphesis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphesis#Noun)* refers to  loss of the initial unstressed vowel of a word.  *Drink* as the verb *to drown* was formed from the older word *adrink*, which if interpreted as an adverb could suggest *in the drink*.